# Callkit CXHandle .generic Type issues

Tags: ios, opentok, callkit

I am using Callkit to receive incoming video calls with the .generic CXHandle type. The functionality works as it should in iOS 14 and below, but with iOS 15 beta 6, the .generic handle type doesn't seem to be working properly. The main issue I am having is that the notifications are coming in all lowercase letters as opposed to capitalizing the first letter of the first and last name. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, after some research I found the `localizedCallerName` property on `CXCallUpdate` you can use to overwrite the callername.

see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcallupdate

This just takes the name and displays it as it is, without making it lowercase.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked